# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier {import React from 'react';

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I am using React in Ruby project with react_on_rails gem
Everything is ok, but when I start Jest test this error appears:

```
/Users/alexandar/projects/ezeewallet.com/app/javascript/bundles/DatePicker/DatePickerRange.jsx:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
                                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (spec/javascripts/member/DatePicker.spec.js:15:24)
```

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",

  },
   ....
```

.babelcr:

```
{
  "presets": [["env", {"modules": false}], "react"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["env"], "react"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {"root": ["./app/javascript"], "alias": {}}],
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    ["transform-class-properties", {"spec": true}]
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Iv forgotten to add x for jsx files in package json:
 "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }

Answer (score 2):

Iv forgotten to add x for jsx files in package json:

```
"jest": { "transform": { "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest" }
```

Now everything is fine